# Agora SDK for Linux C++

Tags: c++, video-streaming, agora.io, agora

I want to add a WebRTC video and audio streaming feature for my Linux C++ application.
Currently, I consider to use Agora Interactive Live Streaming, but it only provides Windows C++ SDK.

Can I use an Agora Windows C++ SDK for Linux C++ application?
If not, is there any good way to use Agora in the Linux C++ application?

I also open to other ways to transmit video and audio in real-time if there is better way.

Comment: A quick look at the Agora shows many supported platforms. Vanilla Linux is weakly supported, but you might be able to use one of the SDKs for platforms that run atop Linux.